# Array type index signature loses specificity when indexed with `number`

Tags: typescript

I recently came across the following TypeScript code.

```
type API = {
    method1: Array<(num: number) => void>,
    method2: Array<(str: string) => void>
}

const methods: API = {
    method1: [],
    method2: []
}

function add<K extends keyof API>(key: K, method: API[K][number]) {
    methods[key].push(method);
}
```

The index signature `API[K]` in the `add` function types correctly. However, once you add the `[number]` at the end to grab the array's underlying type, TypeScript forgets the index signature and instead creates a union of both the function types that appear in type `API`.

This is the error I get in the TypeScript playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggCgSSgXigbwFBW1AthYACwHsATARgC5YAnGgQxAB4AKAOwFddrPcAjCDQCUKAHxQAbsQCWpUQBosOfETIAmajDqNWAZ2A1q+mtLYBzEcnFTZojAF8MGAMbE2+vARKldmxCnQlbBVvKigAbQBdRRxPVVINCMiHJwAzDjZnYGk3KHpSUiYAaSgIAA9gCDYfKABrCBBiVNhEURZ6kGoi+TjvPwRwosjw3gEaSJFMWJCyXXCOyIA6MA5dQhYZ0iEAbhSgA) .

```
Argument of type '((num: number) => void) | ((str: string) => void)' is not assignable to parameter of type '((num: number) => void) & ((str: string) => void)'.
  Type '(num: number) => void' is not assignable to type '((num: number) => void) & ((str: string) => void)'.
    Type '(num: number) => void' is not assignable to type '(str: string) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'num' and 'str' are incompatible.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

Of course, the easy fix is to remove the array types from type `API` and created a mapped type for the `methods` object.

```
type API = {
    method1: (num: number) => void,
    method2: (str: string) => void
}

const methods: { [K in keyof API]: API[K][] } = {
    method1: [],
    method2: []
}

function add<K extends keyof API>(key: K, method: API[K]) {
    methods[key].push(method);
}
```

I'm hoping to understand why the first example doesn't work. Is there something specific about TypeScript that disallows such use of index types? Any insight on this is much appreciated.

Comment: In your 2nd example, `methods[key]` is seen as type `API[K][]`, a single array type with a `push()` method that accepts an `API[K]`. In your 1st example, `methods[key]` is seen as a *union of arrays*, which requires the *intersection of elements* to be `push`ed to it.  The compiler can't "see" the correlation in that first version; see [ms/TS#30581](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) and [ms/TS#47109](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) for more information about the problem and the fix.  I could write that up as an answer if it fully addresses the question. Let me know.

Comment: @jcalz, if you're willing, I'd like to see your explanation of the issue as an answer.

Comment: Sure, I'll do so when I get a chance, might not be for a few hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For ease of discussion I'm going to rename your `API` types to

```
type APIArray = {
    method1: Array<(num: number) => void>,
    method2: Array<(str: string) => void>
}
```

and

```
type APIElement = {
    method1: (num: number) => void,
    method2: (str: string) => void
}
```

so that there's no confusion which `API` we're talking about.

---

TypeScript isn't really able to perform arbitrary analysis over [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) types. There are a few operations it can deal with properly, and otherwise it just takes shortcuts by widening generic type parameters to their [constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints).

---

The problem with your first approach

```
function add<K extends keyof APIArray>(key: K, method: APIArray[K][number]) {
    methods[key].push(method); // error
}
```

is that the type of `methods[key]`, `APIArray[K]`, is not seen as a single array type. When you call the `push()` method, it ends up widening `K` to its constraint, the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `keyof APIArray`, and therefore `method[key].push` is widened to the following union of functions:

```
const m = methods[key].push;
// const m: 
//   ((...items: ((num: number) => void)[]) => number) | 
//   ((...items: ((str: string) => void)[]) => number)
methods[key].push(method); // error
```

A union of functions can only be safely called with an *intersection* of the union members' arguments (see [the TS3.3 release notes describing support for calling unions of functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types)), and so the only thing `methods[key].push` will accept as an argument is something which is *both* a `(num: number) => void` *and* a `(str: string) => void`.  But of course `method` is only going to be one of those, and it fails.

The compiler has lost track of the *correlation* between the type of `methods[key].push` and `method`.  They're just uncorrelated union types, according to its analysis.  Hence it is worried that maybe `methods[key]` will be an array of `string`-accepting methods while `method` will be a `number`-accepting method, and vice versa.  We know this is unlikely, but the compiler can't see it.

(Notice I said *unlikely* and not *impossible*.  This is technically a valid call:

```
// not likely
add(Math.random() < 0.999 ? "method1" : "method2", (s: string) => s.toUpperCase())
```

I'm not going to make this even longer by exploring why that is accepted and in which circumstances this can be prevented. The TS type system isn't fully sound and that things like this sometimes crop up, but it really isn't directly relevant to why your two code versions are treated differently.)

The general lack of support for "correlated unions" is described in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581), and the same problem happens when you have union-constrained generics that the compiler can't analyze properly.

---

On the other hand, your second approach

```
const methods: { [K in keyof APIElement]: APIElement[K][] } = {
    method1: [],
    method2: []
}

function add<K extends keyof APIElement>(key: K, method: APIElement[K]) {
    methods[key].push(method);
}
```

works because the type of `methods[key].push` is seen as a single function that accepts an argument of type `APIElement[K]`, which is exactly the type of `method`:

```
const m = methods[key].push
// const m: (...items: APIElement[K][]) => number
```

It's not a union because the compiler has better support for direct generic [indexed accesses](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).  This support was added/strengthened in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) specifically as a way to help deal with correlated unions.

By writing the type of `methods` explicitly as a mapped type over `APIElement`, you have given the compiler a hint that it indexing into it with a generic index like `key` will result in a *single generic* thing, instead of a *union of specific* things.

So there you go.

---

It's not obvious that this difference should exist, and frankly it takes a lot of explaining and pointing to ms/TS#30581 and ms/TS#47109 whenever people run into this situation.  Usually people hit this by being unable to write the version that works, a stumbling block which you've managed to overcome.  But the issues are the same either way.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.6#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAFATgewEYBsJiQG8AoJMpAFwE8ZkBBFASTrTRCqQF4jTy-IKACwwATAIwAuJCzZUAPAApgAVzBSVYLBDQBKLgD4kANwwBLEfoA0vPmQHCRAJikz2iqBTRSPaU8ADmepyGJub6NkgAvsQR8BjAHkj2olAuTK4c3CS25MniUgDaALrWOXYQQqLOSMUR0REA9A1IwBgUSDimANYQOFQRICIiCgCyIEIAdGzAIhhgCnpySAAMEwCcG0gA-EgARHliu0hS+xUOjruWSAqpSD5+gQZ3ExQYAKowtGgAwiBQEAsdDE+AAzZTAeAUUzxJCDERyADSSAgAA8KBAZlAkD0qBgQdJ0qx2PoFDipAirnk0swiVQCgiigUNFo0EU9NkynEEu0CNw8lACjiihMYMooIIANwRPhNJBcxJqJDS8iysgKBQTTWmdFgW7qjTqVQsoIhMwiHTFE0tI3aPQAHyVZSQquuGq1Or1N083k8DytoXNlqezNtyvKlREAqFIrFggUeR0EudzW0mDQdWB5DBEKhMLhjkRyLRGMj2IguPxDBpshJZKQFKSZ1E1Iy9MZIdZ7LDcviCpbtLbTJtrOKXEbEaj5aKSdlGC67G7YBj4vjTfNM+ac4XfHqxHqoEgsAQyAAYqYUTw+NRaATGABRPCQYDtLKLteSa4G62aW1PAOlMo8mqL0vDuX0An9M0M1iXseTXW5CBqJE-DLCtbwffAMQoIpqQwp8KEHIoojHDkcgOQoSjfCNqlqHdMzIbNIWhYBYSGQtUXRTFULxdDHyw2ty3JSk11wvjnzbLsnXlHkx35QUp2XQRu1laSkikN0Jm1fBbirPCsMIq0OyohxJyoYVRRXBMpToyIgA)

Answer (score 0):

In the [second version](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggCgSSgXigbwFBW1AthYACwHsATARgC4oAKAOwFddrHcAjCAJwEoUA+KADdiAS1IAaLDnxEyAJmo0AzsE7UVnEXQDmvZAOFiMAXwwYAxsToq8BEqSXU0UANoBpKFqgBrCCGIAZrCIALrU8AjuIS4hUMYo6FLYMvZUriGSOLaypArpJmYBDHTmwCJWUACGpKQAPB4QAB7AEHQOPn6BwQh8NL4g1G7i2fbhiFG8mFkpZEou-SEAdGAMSoQ0M6TcANxJUAD0+1nHOAB6APwFQA) the `push` method expects `API[K]` which is the exact type of the argument `method` so it doesn't have to try to resolve any generics to see if it is valid.

In the first version because there is a second level of indirection typescript tries to resolve the generic and determines that `push` needs to take an argument that is compatible with both function signatures but the method will only be one or the other. ([playground link showing the generic replaced with base type and shows the intersection and union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/C4TwDgpgBAggCgSSgXigbwFBW1AthYACwHsATARgC5YAnGgQxAB4AKAOwFddrPcAjCDQCUKAHxQAbsQCWpUQBosOfETIAmajDqNWAZ2A1q+mtLYBzEcnFTZojAF8MGAMbE2+vARKldmxCnQlbBVvKigAbQBdRRxPVVINCMiHDFBIKABpAIAiELJybIAfXK91bIwAMw42Z2BpNyh6UlIAegAqJiyIAA9gCDYfKABrCBBiCthEUTaWlhGQagz5OO8-BHCMyPDeARpIkUxYlpbY07Pzi8uoAD0AfiCVsl1w+ciAOjAOXUIWPNIhADcD2OV2wdwcQA))

I believe this is mainly a limitation of typescript, even explicitly saying you take the same parameters of the `push` method gives the same error: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggCgSSgXigbwFBW1AthYACwHsATARgC5YAnGgQxAB4AKAOwFddrPcAjCDQCUKAHxQAbsQCWpUQBosOfETIAmajDqNWAZ2A1q+mtLYBzEcnFTZojAF8MGAMbE2+vARKldmxCnQlbBVvKigAbQBdRRxPVVINCMiHJwAzDjZnYGk3KHpSUiYAaSgIAA9gCDYfKABrCBBiVKhQSCa4711RFnqQaiL5KAA6EZCyajh6BhVBXSZWiHaxn3CiyPCAIjAOXUINyNERTFjl3XDeyKHt3ZYRoeWhAG4HIA)

```js
function add<K extends keyof typeof methods>(key: K, ...method: Parameters<typeof methods[K]["push"]>) {
    methods[key].push(...method);
// gives same error here ^
}
```

I don't really have better information than this, hopefully someone else with more knowledge of the development history can chime in but I figured I had enough to say that might help to post an answer :)